# Is there a better way to hide a menu when a user clicks off it?

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below to show/hide a navigation menu on click of an anchor.

The problem that I am having is that the first time the page loads, I have to click the anchor twice to get the menu to show. After that, I can toggle the menu with a single click. I can also click off the menu anywhere on the document to hide it.

Does anyone see a problem with the code below or know of a better way for me to hide the menu when a user clicks off the menu?

```
$('#aToggleQuickNavigation').click(function () {
    $('#ulQuickNavigation').toggle();
});

$('html').click(function () {
    if ($('#ulQuickNavigation').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('#ulQuickNavigation').css('display', 'none');
    }
    $('#aToggleQuickNavigation').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#ulQuickNavigation li a').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Generally menus work on mouse-over if they cover any additional port of the page, not click. That way mouse-out closed them, not click. You should reconsider the user experience here.

Comment: You're leaving out anyone who navigates with the keyboard. I'd really recommend going with a burned in solution like superfish.

Comment: can yuo provide the html code? i think you shold use hover not click

Comment: I have very specific requirements for this interface so it's not really up to me. The powers that be also want this to be IPAD friendly so hovers are being kept to a minimum, although in this case I suppose they could use both. I'm sorry but I can't share the HTML, but it's basically an anchor tag wrapped around a word that shows/hides an unordered list on click. Jonathans answer below solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide it if the click event bubbles all the way up to the body:

```
$("body").click(function(){
  $("#ulQuickNavigation").hide();
});
```

If the user clicks anywhere on the menu, you are already preventing the propagation of that click, so the body will never hear of it, and as such it will not be  hidden.

Another thing I noticed is that you're binding your click events within the click event handler of the HTML element. This can be pretty problematic. Each time a click bubbles up to the HTML element, you will be binding more and more click events.

Just stick with something like this for now:

```
// Any click that arrives at the body should close my navigation
$("body").click(function(){
  $("#ulQuickNavigation").hide();
});

// Prevent clicks on nav from reaching the body
$("#ulQuickNavigation").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much Jonathan. This solved my problem. Oddly enough I'm using hide() on another section of the site. Not sure how I overlooked it. I guess I got too distracted trying to figure out why my code didn't work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the jQuery built in slideToggle functionality?

Basically it takes an element with display: none; on it and will display it on click (or wherever you set the change logic).

Example:

`$("#ID").slideToggle(700);`

where 700 is the time in milliseconds you want the slide toggle to take.

In your case:

`$('#aToggleQuickNavigation').click(function () {
        $('#ulQuickNavigation').slideToggle(500);
    });`

Comment: Thanks MrShmee. I have very specific requirements for this interface so slideToggle wouldn't be appropriate.